# Bounce invalid email timing

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

In one Journey Builder, we have the need to use an engagement bounce after 24 h from the email send.

As stated in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_bounced_email_messages.htm&type=5), the best practice is to wait for the bounce at least 72h.

Our client wants to get the bounce caused by an "invalid email" within 24h.

Is it available to use this time if we want to get those specific kinds of bounce (user unknown and domain unknown)?

Is there any statistics that states this percentage of bounce/time, for instance:

- 60% come within 24h
- 20% after 48h

If not, are there any other solutions that I could use?

Comment: SF Support can reduce that 72-hour threshold.

Comment: thanks @AdamSpriggs, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Delivery is retried for 72 hours before a bounce event is registered.  SF Support can reduce this period.